# what should i do i keep getting ORA-01861: literal does not match format string ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting ORA-01861: literal does not match format string ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

what shoud i do?

```
create table TASK (
    TASK_ID number not null constraint task_pk primary key,
    TASK_DESCRIP varchar2(50) not null,
    TASK_STARTING_DATE date not null,
    TASK_ENDING_DATE date not null,
    NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEE number not null
);

INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(1101,'Initial interview','2018-03-01','2018-03-06','3');
```

Comment: Please see my edits. First, I put your code in a code block. This is easy to do: highlight the text and then press the `{}` button in the editor. Then, I added the tag `oracle`. Please always tag your SQL requests which the DBMS you are using in order to get appropriate answers.

Comment: Note that the 3 should be a number, not a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are simply missing the keyword `DATE`.

In your insert statement you have `'2018-03-01'`. This is a string literal, but the table column that is to receive this value is of  data type `DATE`. This means Oracle must convert the string to a date. Now `'2018-03-01'` is not a date format that is commonly used in your country / region, so Oracle doesn't know how to safely convert it (e.g. how to decide which is day and which is month).

Use a date literal instead. For this we must use the keyword `DATE` followed by the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, which is what you are probably already using. Hence:

```
INSERT INTO task
  (task_id, task_descrip, task_starting_date, task_ending_date, number_of_employee)
  VALUES(1101, 'Initial interview', DATE '2018-03-01', DATE '2018-03-06', 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the date format your date should have. You can use TO_DATE for that. As example:

```
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(1101,'Initial interview',
TO_DATE('2018-03-01','YYYY-DD-MM'),
TO_DATE('2018-03-06','YYYY-DD-MM'),3);
```

If your date should be formatted the other way, just write 'YYYY-MM-DD' instead of 'YYYY-DD-MM'.
See here please: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=217037bf09346d17174148c72c0c9929)